# ExtJS 5 Using a Combobox with a trigger in CellEditing Grid

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

I am having a issue when using a cell editing grid that has a field that opens a window. The issue is when you open the editor for the field and click on one of the combobox triggers, a window opens, which causes the field to fire validateedit, resulting in the editor closing. I am looking for a way to prevent this. The reason that I am opening a window is that I am giving the user the ability to quickly add a new record to the combobox, without having to go to another place in the system. I am able to get this functionality to work with row editing but my customer does not like they way row editing works.

[Here is my fiddle example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1duq)